# awk search help

Tags: search, awk

I need help with a simple awk script for matching letters on a lines.

For example, Finding separate matches for KJ in one field and finding matches for KP in the next?

```
Name       VT       Kip     Rand
NINA        K        K       kevdhekdmabr2738
NINA        J        P       pdbkemgwjsabeb483
NINA        A        J       meveahsbkdemjep48328
NINA        P        K       ehkmskdldadvsvpm46383
NINA        M        P       zbdamshasjerrj3738   
NINA        J        K       amfjekspdbejd34549
NINA        P        M       pokjdokdam2452355235
```

As you can see the all the the Rand column has a series of letters that match my needed letters.
If have tried `awk '/nina/ && /K/ && /J/ && /K/ && /P/ {print $0}' sampfile.txt`

Is there a way to do this without referring to a specific column/field?

Comment: I don't understand your specs. Could you edit to explain it a little better? For example what lines from the example input would you like in the output?

Comment: Basically, output data that matches KJ in one column and KP in the next.

Comment: What do you mean by `KJ` and `KP`? Either character? In that order? Again, it'd really help if you could just [edit] to show us which of those example lines you want to match.

Comment: did you want to print the lines which contains J next to K?

Comment: For thwe above example what's your expected output?

Comment: did you want this `awk '/ K /{var=$0; getline; if ($2=="J") {printf var"\n"$0"\n"}}' file`. Explain your question clearly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you have against named columns. If you want to specify what's in them, you need to call them out specifically.

```
awk 'NR>1 && $2~/^[KJ]$/ && $3~/^[KP]$/ {print $1}' ...
```

That will match `K-K`, `K-P`, `J-K` and `J-P` and print the name column. It'll also skip the first line which looks like a header.

It matches the following lines from your example:

```
NINA        K        K       kevdhekdmabr2738
NINA        J        P       pdbkemgwjsabeb483
NINA        J        K       amfjekspdbejd34549
```

But obviously only prints the `NINA`.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you want to display the rows that match this condition:

Each line contains two tokens of "K" in any column and the following row contains:
"J" token in the same column of first "K" and "P" token in the same column of second "K"

This program it does what you need

```
     BEGIN { nlines = 0; }              
     {   
       lines[nlines] = $0;   
       kfound[nlines] = "";   
       jfound[nlines] = "";   
       pfound[nlines] = "";   
       for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
          if ($(i) == "K") kfound[nlines] = kfound[nlines] " " i;
          if ($(i) == "J") jfound[nlines] = i;
          if ($(i) == "P") pfound[nlines] = i;   
       }   
       nlines++; 
     } 
     END {   
        for(i=0;i<nlines;i++) {
           ntok = split(kfound[i],tok," ");
           if (ntok < 2) continue;
           if (tok[1] == jfound[i+1] && tok[2] == pfound[i+1]) {
              print lines[i];
              print lines[i+1];
           }   
        } 
     }
```

Save in file test.awk and try:

```
awk -f test.awk fileWithInputLine.txt
```